# All processes have already been run

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a Model in ModelBuilder, and I did not do any special manipulation, but when I am running Model I am getting error:

> All processes have already been run

I tried to remove intermediate data and re-run ArcMap, but it did not help.

Comment: If you've run your script already, click the Check mark button (Validate Entire Model) to reset all the tools to 'not run yet'.

Comment: @GISGe I did it and now I am getting message: "None of the processes are ready to run"

Comment: Then there are missing parameters in one or more tools. Open each tool and make sure your inputs exist, all required parameters are set, etc.

Comment: Don't add information in the comments.  Edit your question to include any new information so people don't have to mine the comments for details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into your model, click on the 'Model' menu dropdown, and select 'Run Entire Model':

[image]

If you are getting 'None of the processes are ready to run' you need to look at your model.  If any of the tools are white, you need to fix the parameters.  In the following image, the 'Collect Values' tool is ready to run.  The 'Iterate Multivalue' tool is not ready to run because I need to set the parameters:

[image]